# PHP: echoing a constant with a variable name

Tags: php, variables, constants

How can I do that?

I have something like:

```
define($stuff.'_FOO', 'whatever');
echo $stuff.'_FOO';
```

and it doesn't work :(

I just want to echo the constant's value...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out [`constant()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

In your case:

```
echo constant($stuff . '_FOO');
```

Answer (score 8):

First make a constant:

```
define("FOO_BAR", "something more");
```

then you can get the value by using `constant()`:

```
echo constant("FOO_BAR");
```

Read more about constants in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Comment: Note the OP is creating the constant name from a variable. So `$stuff` is intentional.

Comment: yes, and I have a justified reason :D (need it to generate error messages for a set of forms, and the constant name contains the form ID)